# Part of variable being dynamic

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to do the following in sass (scss),

`$colors-#{$type}`

but I get

> undefined variable $colors-

I found a source that was refering to the 3.3 [release document](http://blog.sass-lang.com/posts/184094-sass-33-is-released), they do *mention* it, however, I can't find the solution to the issue.

Is there a way to do this?

[link to scss](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/7e1eaf9269c5a1a266b0b79a1a7714e9)

Comment: I can't think of a situation when you'd want to do this. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm doing a generic function for colors, so it uses different maps for different types (main colors, text color ect...), take a look at my example. Il can solve it by using if, but, if more color maps are added I have to modify the function, and it's a cleaner approach. I'm not gone go a distance to solve it @JamesKing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the post is misleading. Each issue I found on Github (for instance [here](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1450) or [here](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/132)) recommend the use of a map. And on https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/463 one of the contributors wrote:

> We've decided to add an association data type (aka map/hash) and it will address this use case.

Use a map and `map-get()` to get your style definitions dynamically. You can use it within a mixin, a function or directly. The following example

```
$colors: (
  "green": #0c0,
  "blue": #00c,
  "red": #c00
);

@mixin my_color($color) {
  color: map-get($colors, $color);
}

@function my_color_func($color) {
  @return map-get($colors, $color);
}

body {
  @include my_color("green");  // use a mixin

  background-color: my_color_func("blue");  // use of a function

  border: 1px solid map-get($colors, "red");  // use directly
}
```

generates the following css:

```
body {
  color: #0c0;
  background-color: #00c;
  border: 1px solid #c00;
}
```